# Process vsserv.exe attempts connection to unknown host (clients.your-server.de)

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

from past few day I notice a new connection is being made from my system, I discovered it within the outpost firewall, it is blocked by default with the reason `Block Transit Packets`

[image]

in the image above you can see that the process vsserv.exe is attempting a connection to `static.88-198-155-41.clients.your-server.de`

I tried to search on google but could not find any relevant info, however this link http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/3963600.htm says that `your-server.de hosts bad bots`.

I am bit concerned if something is not correct. Could you help me understand the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process `vsserv.exe` is Bitdefender and the [ip address belongs to Bitdefender](https://network-tools.webwiz.co.uk/ip-information.htm?ip=88.198.155.41). I think this is the update of the virus signatures you see. So everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I recently installed bitdefender antivirus. Also may thanks for the link to the network tools. I hope that may help me in future to identify similar issues.